# Consulta anidada en MySQL y paginación

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

Tengo el problema de crear una consulta anidada para generar paginacion con resultados que tengo que obtener de 2 tablas diferentes:

[image: Estructura de la las tablas que se utilizan]

algunos registros de las tablas

[image: Contenido de las tablas]

lo que necesito hacer en la consulta es seleccionar 5 registros(por la paginacion) de la tabla registro con el estado de "PENDIENTE" pero solo los que pertenescan a un maestro, por ejemplo "Sandra" espero me explique bien, gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La forma mas simple de entender seria utilizando una subconsulta:

Lo que tienes en comun es la columna de `matricula` la cual esta presente en ambas tablas, por lo cual si sabes que matriculas pertenecen a "Sandra" y miras los registros asociados a dicha matricula obtenedras el resultado que buscas:

Obener las matriculas en las que "Sandra" es profesora:

```
SELECT matricula 
  FROM alumnos
  WHERE maestro="Sandra";
```

Esta consulta te devuelve las matriculas, por lo tanto ahora solo tienes que buscar que registros tienen estas matriculas.

```
SELECT *
  FROM registros
  WHERE matricula IN (SELECT matricula 
                     FROM alumnos
                     WHERE maestro="Sandra") AS dato 
// A toda subconsulta hace falta añadir un alias "AS algo"
```

---

Tambien se puede utilizar  [Inner Join](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-inner-join.aspx)

```
SELECT idregistro,
       idproblema,
       registro.matricula,
       hora,
       fecha,
       estado,
       observacion
  FROM registro
  INNER JOIN alumnos ON registro.matricula=alumnos.matricula
  WHERE alumnos.maestro = "Sandra";
```

> Aunque una subconsulta es a primera vista mas fácil de entender el funcionamiento, a la hora de ejecutarse es mas rápida una INNER JOIN por lo que toda subconsulta que pueda ser substituida por un INNER JOIN para hacer el mismo trabajo es recomendable hacerlo.

Comment: y para solo traer los registros de la maestra Sandra pero solo lo que su estado es pendiente? disculpa la ignorancia

Comment: lo digo para la consulta de INNER JOIN

Comment: En la `subsconsulta`  simplemente añadiedo `WHERE estado="pendiente"` al final del todo y en la `inner Join` al final del todo despues de "Sandra" añades `AND estado="pendiente"`